# How to loop combination of variables from xml-file and save in new xml-file in R

Tags: r, xml

I currently have a large xml-file with a lot of variables which I want to change and export in a new xml file with the help of R. 
Here is the beginning of my xml file (it stays quiet the same until the end)

```
<Assemblies count="4">
<Assembly index="0">
  <IdentNr>2</IdentNr>
  <IDNr_DB>0</IDNr_DB>
  <Name>Decke D1</Name>
  <Order_Layers choice="von außen nach innen">2</Order_Layers>
  <Grid_Kind choice="Mittel">2</Grid_Kind>
  <Layers count="5">
    <Layer index="0">
      <Thickness unit="m">0.003</Thickness>
      <Material>
        <IDNr_DB>1203</IDNr_DB>
        <Name>Linoleum nach DIN 18171</Name>
        <ThermalConductivity unit="W/mK">0.17</ThermalConductivity>
        <BulkDensity unit="kg/m³">1000</BulkDensity>
        <Porosity unit="-">0.23</Porosity>
        <HeatCapacity unit="J/kgK">1500</HeatCapacity>
        <WaterVaporResistance unit="-">6250</WaterVaporResistance>
        <ReferenceWaterContent unit="kg/m³" />
        <FreeWaterSaturation unit="kg/m³" />
        <WaterAbsorptionCoefficient unit="kg/m²s^0.5" />
        <MoistureSupplement unit="%/M.-%" />
        <TempDepThermalCondSupplement unit="W/mK²" />
        <TypicalMoisture unit="kg/m³" />
   <Layer index="1">
      <Thickness unit="m">0.02</Thickness>
      <Material>
        <IDNr_DB>1039</IDNr_DB>
        <Name>Zement Fließestrich, obere Schicht</Name>
        <ThermalConductivity unit="W/mK">1.6</ThermalConductivity>
        <BulkDensity unit="kg/m³">1890</BulkDensity>
        <Porosity unit="-">0.2</Porosity>
        <HeatCapacity unit="J/kgK">850</HeatCapacity>
        <WaterVaporResistance unit="-">58</WaterVaporResistance>
        <ReferenceWaterContent unit="kg/m³">37.8</ReferenceWaterContent>
        <FreeWaterSaturation unit="kg/m³">168</FreeWaterSaturation>
        <WaterAbsorptionCoefficient unit="kg/m²s^0.5">0.025</WaterAbsorptionCoefficient>
        <MoistureSupplement unit="%/M.-%" />
        <TempDepThermalCondSupplement unit="W/mK²">0.0002</TempDepThermalCondSupplement>
        <TypicalMoisture unit="kg/m³">168</TypicalMoi
```

I've already got a code with a foreach loop, but I need to change a ton of variables. Here is the example with 2 loops which exports 6 new files

```
library(XML)
doc  <- xmlTreeParse("d:\\Users\\Documents\\raum-klima-putz\\R\\TestXML\\test.xml", getDTD = F)
r    <- xmlRoot(doc)
ExpPath <- "d:\\Users\\Documents\\raum-klima-putz\\R\\TestXML3"
example.weatherfile <- c("d:\\Users\\Documents\\raum-klima-putz\\R\\WetterdatenJuni2017\\2032_Karlsruhe.epw", "d:\\Users\\Documents\\raum-klima-putz\\R\\WetterdatenJuni2017\\2032_Karlsruhe_swdirnorm.epw", "Test")
example.thickness <- c("12","20","21")
for (i in 1:length(example.weatherfile))
  {
xmlValue(r[["Variants"]][[1]][["ClimateLocation"]][["FileName"]]) <- example.weatherfile[i]
xmlValue(r[["Assemblies"]][[1]][["Layers"]][[1]][["Thickness"]]) <- example.thickness[i]
FileName      <- paste("Weather_neu",i, ".xml", sep="");
saveXML(r, file=paste(ExpPath, FileName, sep = "\\"), compression=0, prefix = NULL);
}
for (i in 1:length(example.thickness))
  {
xmlValue(r[["Variants"]][[1]][["ClimateLocation"]][["FileName"]]) <- example.weatherfile[i]
xmlValue(r[["Assemblies"]][[1]][["Layers"]][[1]][["Thickness"]]) <- example.thickness[i]
FileName      <- paste("Thickness_neu",i, ".xml", sep="");
saveXML(r, file=paste(ExpPath, FileName, sep = "\\"), compression=0, prefix = NULL);
}
```

but instead of creating a forsearch loop for each combination of variables I want to create sort of a matrix so I can get a combinbination of all the parameters, e.g. in case of 10 parameters: a matrix of 10x10 which gets 100 new files. So the first parameter gets replaced by 3 variables and combined with all the other parameters, then the second parameter and so on.
Is there an easier way to create these variations than to write a foreach loop for every parameter?
Thank you

Comment: The XML appears to be incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

This might work to get you what you are after.

```
library(XML)

doc  <- xmlTreeParse("d:\\Users\\Documents\\raum-klima-putz\\R\\TestXML\\test.xml", getDTD = F)
r    <- xmlRoot(doc)

ExpPath <- "d:\\Users\\Documents\\raum-klima-putz\\R\\TestXML3"

example.weatherfile <- c("d:\\Users\\Documents\\raum-klima-putz\\R\\WetterdatenJuni2017\\2032_Karlsruhe.epw", "d:\\Users\\Documents\\raum-klima-putz\\R\\WetterdatenJuni2017\\2032_Karlsruhe_swdirnorm.epw", "Test")
example.thickness <- c("12","20","21")

# Create dataframe with all combinations of weatherfiles and thicknesses
all.combos <- expand.grid(example.weatherfile, example.thickness)
# Add a column for row number
all.combos$rownum <- c(1:nrow(all.combos))

# Apply the custom function to all rows of the all.combos dataframe
apply(all.combos, 1, function(x){
                       # x is a vector of the current row being processed
                       # x[1] is the current weatherfile
                       # x[2] is the current thickness
                       # x[3] is the current row number
                       xmlValue(r[["Variants"]][[1]][["ClimateLocation"]][["FileName"]]) <- x[1]
                       xmlValue(r[["Assemblies"]][[1]][["Layers"]][[1]][["Thickness"]]) <- x[2]
                       FileName <- paste("Weather_neu",x[3], ".xml", sep="");
                       saveXML(r, file=paste(ExpPath, FileName, sep = "\\"), compression=0, prefix = NULL)})
```